# How does the golang cgo linker work on macos?

Tags: macos, go

On some systems, the project https://github.com/nilleb/fsevents-watcher
produces a `fsevents_watcher.so` linked to the HomeBrew python. While on other systems it is linked to the system Python.

Which environment variables/configuration elements influence the cgo linker on MacOSX?

I am asking this question for a user who has the homebrew python as the first in his $PATH, but obtains a `.so` linked against the system python.

Comment: Not sure offhand, but you can see exactly how every build command is run with the `-x` flag.

Comment: thanks JimB, now I have a clearer view of the command being issued (and potentially I can change it -- since it is one of the latest being issued). It would be interesting to know how the command is being assembled...

```
clang -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK/b001=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common -o $WORK/b001/_cgo_.o $WORK/b001/_cgo_main.o $WORK/b001/_x001.o $WORK/b001/_x002.o $WORK/b001/_x003.o -g -O2 -L/usr/local/opt/python@2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -lpython2.7
```

Comment: That package is using pkg-config to specifically find python-2.7